# Excel 2003: Extracting results of calculations

Tags: excel, excel-2003, excel-formula, vba

I would like to know if there is a way to link a cell such that it holds the results of a calculation permanently so that even when the input to the calculation is changed, the previous result is still saved.

To further illustrate, for example, when lets say my calculation is x+2=y and x = 1 in the first case. I want to be able to link a cell to save the result y=3 and also the input x =1, even when I change the value of x.

A possible solution to do use an IF condition and a PASTE SPECIAL command together, but I am not sure how to programme it such that it is automated. Is there a way to do this using formulas? Or must I venture into VBA?

Answer (score 1):

> > > A possible solution to do use an IF condition and a PASTE SPECIAL command together, but I am not sure how to programme it such that it is automated. Is there a way to do this using formulas? Or must I venture into VBA?

Here is one way without the need of PASTE SPECIAL command.  Paste the code in **relevant** Worksheet code area. Please refer to the **snapshot 1**. This is just an example. Please change it as per your requirements. What the code does is, it checks if the user entered any Value of X (Cell A2) and if the user did then capture it captures the value of Y(Cell B2) and stores it in Col D. Please refer to **snapshot 2**.

[image]

**Snapshot 1**

[image]

**Snapshot 2**

And this is the complete code. One piece of caution though. Do not try this code without the "**.EnableEvents = False**" or without the error handling in your main sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    
    '~~> Check if any value was entered in cell A2
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = False
        End With
        
        '~~> Get the next available line in Col D for output
        LastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        '~~> Save the value
        Range("D" & LastRow).Value = Range("B2").Value
    End If
    
LetsContinue:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

HTH

Sid

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the value of cell y and paste - values only - in another cell.
Right Click -> Paste Special --> Select 'values'

Comment: Hi, I am aware of how to use paste special. I would like to know how I can program it so that certain cells behave in that way and hold the values of y permanently and do not change when x is changed. Perhaps, a way to stop it from re-evaluating?

Comment: so you want a list of cells that store the values of y for each x?

Comment: Yes, is it possible to do so?